# How long does the vision from a scan last in Starcraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

How long does the vision from a scan last in Starcraft 2?

How many real-time seconds does it last at "Faster" game speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [scanner sweep](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Scanner_Sweep) lasts 12.3 seconds in game time.

Using math found [here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Game_Speed) the faster time speed is approximately 1.38 times faster than normal time which is a 1 to 1 ratio. The scanner sweep lasts 8.91 seconds. (12.3/1.38) or (12.3 * 0.725)

Comment: +1 I have no idea if this is true, but the extra ".3" at the end makes it seem like you know what you're talking about.

Comment: yeah, how did they measure the 0.3?

Comment: Team Liquid is pretty much the most definitive source on anything Starcraft related. How they measured that .3 is not to my knowledge, but if I had to venture a guess is that someone took a replay and measured it frame by frame.

Answer (score 2):

The scanner sweep lasts 12 in game seconds. This is scaled by the game speed you are playing on. The tooltip in game should tell you this.

Faster game speed applies a 1.4x multiplier to the speed. So the scan will last for 12seconds/1.4 = 8.58 seconds of real time.

Reference:
http://sc2pod.com/wiki/Orbital_Command

Comment: Good point on game speed. I'll edit my question

Comment: The "faster" game speed is a time dilation of 1.4x normal speed. So you just need to divide the sweep time on the tooltip (12s) by the time dilation (1.4). The answer is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Darn Teofrostus giving away the answer!